# What is the best way to upload image to server and save it to local storage in Android?

Tags: java, android

I implemented code to upload an image to local storage and send them to server, but i got the error look like below :

```
 E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.smanggin.amatra/com.smanggin.amatra.sales.ui.transaction.sales.pcv.Detail.PcvDetailListActivity/42
2019-11-05 13:27:30.690 20905-20905/com.smanggin.amatra E/PCVVIEW: is_sent --> null
2019-11-05 13:27:30.707 20905-20905/com.smanggin.amatra E/Database: Error inserting <redacted values> into pcv_header
    net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: UNIQUE constraint failed: pcv_header.id
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:58)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:2074)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1930)
        at com.smanggin.amatra.sales.model.PcvView$PcvDB.insert(PcvView.java:251)
        at com.smanggin.amatra.sales.ui.transaction.sales.pcv.PcvViewActivity.createIdLocal(PcvViewActivity.java:715)
        at com.smanggin.amatra.sales.ui.transaction.sales.pcv.PcvViewActivity.access$000(PcvViewActivity.java:58)
        at com.smanggin.amatra.sales.ui.transaction.sales.pcv.PcvViewActivity$1.onBottomSheetItemClick(PcvViewActivity.java:271)
        at com.github.rubensousa.bottomsheetbuilder.BottomSheetMenuDialog.onBottomSheetItemClick(BottomSheetMenuDialog.java:182)
        at com.github.rubensousa.bottomsheetbuilder.adapter.BottomSheetItemAdapter$ItemViewHolder.onClick(BottomSheetItemAdapter.java:208)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6673)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6650)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:792)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26213)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7217)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:575)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:887)
2019-11-05 13:27:30.735 3655-8317/? E/neodaemon: ERROR  elsaGetPackageFreezing is NULL
2019-11-05 13:27:30.742 1928-9379/? E/OifaceUtil: Cannot connect to OifaceService
2019-11-05 13:27:30.749 3655-8317/? E/neodaemon: ERROR  elsaGetPackageFreezing is NULL
2019-11-05 13:27:30.849 3655-8317/? E/neodaemon: ERROR  elsaGetPackageFreezing is NULL
2019-11-05 13:27:30.857 3655-8317/? E/neodaemon: ERROR  elsaGetPackageFreezing is NULL
2019-11-05 13:27:30.867 3655-8317/? E/neodaemon: ERROR  elsaGetPackageFreezing is NULL
2019-11-05 13:27:30.870 20905-20905/com.smanggin.amatra E/PCVDETAILLISTACTIVITY: Query Load Data : SELECT pd.*, i.name as item_name FROM pcv_detail as pd LEFT JOIN item as i on pd.item_id = i.id WHERE pd.pcv_id = -1
```

This is my ImageListActivity

```
public class ImageListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;

    private static final String TAG = ImageListActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Toolbar toolbar;

    ExpandableHeightGridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;
    Uri file;

    Attachment attachment;
    Attachment.AttachmentDB attachmentDB;

    String file_name;
    String model_id;
    String model_name;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String url = "http://192.168.1.7:8080/mobilesales/upload/attachment/pcv/";

    @TargetApi(17)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list);

        setTitle("Photo List");

        initVariable();

        initToolbar();

        initGrid();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SaveImage(this);
    }

    private void initVariable() {
        model_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("model_name");
        model_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("model_id");

        attachment = new Attachment();
        attachmentDB = attachment.new AttachmentDB(this);
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void initGrid() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        gridView.setExpanded(true);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(ImageListActivity.this, ImageViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_menu_photo_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public String getModel_id()
    {
        return model_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_camera:
                takePicture();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * prepare image untuk ditampilkan di gridview
     */
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Commons.PCV_PHOTO_DIR_NAME);
        Cursor res = attachmentDB.getAttachment(model_id);
        Log.w(TAG, "getData--> res.getCount(): " + res.getCount());
        try {
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String file_name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("file_name"));
                    Log.e(TAG, "getData--> file_name: " + file_name);
                    File filePath = new File(path, file_name);
                    Bitmap bitmap;

                    if (filePath.exists()) {
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        options.inSampleSize = 8;
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath.toString(), options);
                        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, file_name));
                        Commons.showToast(ImageListActivity.this, "DATA SUDAH ADA SEBELUMNYYA : " + file_name, true);
                    }
                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error while trying to get posts from database");
        } finally {
            if (res != null && !res.isClosed()) {
                res.close();
            }
        }
        return imageItems;
    }

    public void btnUploadClick(View view) {
        confirmUploadDialog(this);
    }

    /**
     * buka kamera
     */
    public void takePicture() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList <ImageItem> SaveImage(final Context context){
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        final Cursor res = attachmentDB.getAttachment(model_id);
        final String url = Commons.getServerUrl(this);
        Log.e(TAG, " getImage --> res.getCount() : " +res.getCount());
        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        class SaveThisImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progress.setTitle("Processing");
                progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                progress.setCancelable(false);
                progress.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                try {
                    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            String fileName = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("file_name"));
                            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String file_Name = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Commons.PCV_PHOTO_DIR_NAME);
                            dir.mkdirs();
                            final File myImageFile = new File(dir, fileName); // Create image file
                            FileOutputStream fos = null;
                            try {
                                fos = new FileOutputStream(myImageFile);
                                Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(url+"/upload/attachment/pcv/"+fileName).get();
                                Log.e(TAG, "url photo--> " +Picasso.with(context).load(url+"/upload/attachment/pcv/"+fileName).get());
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
                                imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, fileName));
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                                intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(myImageFile));
                                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    fos.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        } while (res.moveToNext());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(progress.isShowing()){
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Image Saved");
            }
        }
        SaveThisImage shareimg = new SaveThisImage();
        shareimg.execute();
        return imageItems;
    }


    public File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Commons.PCV_PHOTO_DIR_NAME);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        file_name = Commons.getCurrentDateTime("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        /*file_name = file_name.replace("-", "");
        file_name = file_name.replace(":", "");
        file_name = file_name.replace(" ", "");*/
        file_name = "amatra_img_" + file_name + ".jpg";

        Log.w(TAG, "getOutputMediaFile--> file_name: " + file_name);

        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                file_name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            insertAttachment(file_name);
            restartActivity();
        }
    }

    /**
     * restart activity, biar ke-update
     */
    private void restartActivity() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * dialog untuk confirm upload ke server
     * @param context
     */
    private void confirmUploadDialog(final Context context){
        final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                new ContextThemeWrapper(context,android.R.style.Theme_Dialog))
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Confirmation");
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to upload photo(s) to server?");
        alert.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_confirm);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        uploadAttachment();
                    }
                });
        alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alert.show();
    }

    /**
     * insert ke table attachment
     */
    private void insertAttachment(String file_name) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("file_name", file_name);
        contentValues.put("date_created", Commons.getCurrentDateTime2());
        contentValues.put("last_updated", Commons.getCurrentDateTime2());
        contentValues.put("version", 0);
        contentValues.put("file_types_id", 1);
        contentValues.put("sales_order_id", model_id);
        contentValues.put("doc_id", model_id);


        attachmentDB.insertAttachment(contentValues);
    }

    /**
     * prepare attachment untuk di-upload ke server
     */
    private List<Map<String, Object>> generateAttachment() {
        Cursor res = attachmentDB.generateAttachment(model_id);
        List<Map<String, Object>> attachments = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        try {
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
                    m.put("fileName", "'" + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("file_name")) + "'");
                    m.put("fileTypesId", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("file_types_id")));

                    Log.e(TAG, "fileName --> " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("file_name")) + "'");
                    Log.e(TAG, "fileTypesId --> " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("file_types_id")));


                    attachments.add(m);

                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error while trying to get posts from database");
        } finally {
            if (res != null && !res.isClosed()) {
                res.close();
            }
        }

        return attachments;
    }



    /**
     * upload attachment ke server
     */
    private void uploadAttachment() {
        Commons.showProgressDialog2(progressDialog, "Please wait...");
        ApiServiceSalesOrder apiService = ApiClient.getClient(getApplicationContext()).create(ApiServiceSalesOrder.class);

        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

        builder.addFormDataPart("pcvDetailId", model_id);
        builder.addFormDataPart("model", model_name);
        builder.addFormDataPart("atts", generateAttachment().toString());


        Log.e(TAG, "generateAttachment().size()-->: " + generateAttachment().size());
        Log.e(TAG, "generateAttachment --> id/model_id "  + model_id);
        Log.e(TAG, "generateAttachment --> : " + model_name);
        Log.e(TAG, "generateAttachment --> : " + generateAttachment().toString());

        for (int i=0; i < generateAttachment().size(); i++) {
            File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Commons.PCV_PHOTO_DIR_NAME);
            Map<String, Object> m = generateAttachment().get(i);
            String file_name = m.get("fileName").toString();
            //String file_name = "amatra_img_20171015082958.jpg";
            File filePath = new File(path, file_name.replace("'",""));


            Log.w(TAG, "uploadAttachment--> file_name: " + file_name.replace("'",""));

            builder.addFormDataPart("fileUpload" + i, filePath.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), filePath));
        }
// iteration for image
//        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++) {
//            File file = new File(filePaths.get(i));
//            RequestBody requestImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
//            builder.addFormDataPart("event_images[]", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file));
//        }

        MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
        Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.upload2(requestBody);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Commons.showToast(ImageListActivity.this, "Success", true);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Commons.showToast(ImageListActivity.this, "Failed", true);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my ImageViewActivity

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");

        TextView titleTextView = findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTextView.setText(title);

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

This my Photo class

```
public class Photo extends AppCompatActivity {
//    String URL="192.168.0.103:8080/mobilesales/upload/attachment/pcv/Hydrangeas.jpg";
    String URL="192.168.0.103:8080/mobilesales/upload/attachment/pcv/";
    private Button btnsave;
    private ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photolist_view);
        img= findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        btnsave= findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        //desplay image
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(URL)
                .into(img);
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(URL)
                        .into(new Target() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                                try {
                                    File mydie = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/HIR_IMG");
                                    if (!mydie.exists()) {
                                        mydie.mkdirs();
                                    }
                                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(mydie, new Date().toString() + ".jpg"));
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream);
                                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                                    fileOutputStream.close();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e2) {
                                    e2.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my SaveImageHelper

```
public class SaveImageHelper implements Target {
    private Context context;
    private WeakReference<AlertDialog> alertDialogWeakReference;
    private WeakReference<ContentResolver> contentResolverWeakReference;
    private String name;
    private String desc;


public  SaveImageHelper(Context context, AlertDialog alertDialog, ContentResolver contentResolver, String name, String desc) {
    this.alertDialogWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(alertDialog);
    this.contentResolverWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(contentResolver);
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
}

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        ContentResolver r = contentResolverWeakReference.get();
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogWeakReference.get();
        if (r != null)
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(r, bitmap,name,desc);
        dialog.dismiss();

        //Open galery after download
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
    }
}
```

I was trying to figure out of this problem but still stuck and did not have any solution, i hope someone can help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: PcvView has the error, but you're not showing that code

Comment: sorry here is the pvcActivity : https://pastebin.com/wXabkWen

Comment: Your problem has not much to do with uploading looking at the logcat `at com.smanggin.amatra.sales.ui.transaction.sales.pcv.PcvViewActivity.createIdLocal(PcvViewActivity.java:715)
        at com.smanggin.amatra.sales.ui.transaction.sales.pcv.PcvViewActivity.access$000(PcvViewActivity.java:58)
        at com.smanggin.amatra.sales.ui.transaction.sales.pcv.PcvViewActivity$1.onBottomSheetItemClick(PcvViewActivity.java:271)
        at com.github.rubensousa.bottomsheetbuilder.BottomSheetMenuDialog.onBottomSheetItemClick(BottomSheetMenuDialog.java:182)`.

Comment: You can remove all code here and just post the code from that activity here. Dont use pastebin.